# Running a scala program with the java tool / scala main function

Tags: java, scala, command-line, jar, console-application

I have a scala app with an `object` which implements `def main(args:Array[String]): Unit` trait. I use the `sbtAssembly` plugin to create a fat jar, and I can run it from the console using:

```
scala myjar.jar
```

However, I want to hand this over to colleagues who don't have scala installed, but only the jdk/jre. So I tried to run this with java, however it fails:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

What do I have to do in order to be able to run it with `java`? Is this even possible?

Comment: How is the assembly plugin set up? Does it exclude the Scala standard library (something like https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-scala-library-jars)? Can you check whether `scala/collection/Seq.class` is in your fat jar?

Comment: Perfect! That was indeed the missing part, it was set to `includeScala = false`. After changing to `true`, I was able to run it using `java -jar myjar.jar`. 
If you add this hint as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a jar using just `java -jar` without specifying a classpath, it must include all dependencies, including the standard Scala library (and from the error message we can see that's what's missing). By default sbt-assembly includes it, but it can be configured [to exclude it](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-scala-library-jars) and that's what your build does. Simply remove `includeScala = false` (or set it to `true`).